# verifying numeric value for activerecord validation when condition is set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, rspec-rails

I'm trying to set a limit for amounts in transfers from different banks, I'm setting a validation on model that evaluates if account's bank of recipient differs from the one it's performing the transfer. However, validation is not working as expected, since it's not allowing to perform the action even if amount is less than the limit already set.

Here's the test I performed:

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe Transfer, type: :model do
  context "creates transfers" do
    before do
      @bank1 = Bank.create(name: "Bank A")
      @bank2 = Bank.create(name: "Bank B")
      @account1 = Account.create(holder: "Jim", bank: @bank1, funds: 25000)
      @account2 = Account.create(holder: "Emma", bank: @bank2, funds: 2000)
      @account3 = Account.create(holder: "Todd", bank: @bank1, funds: 5500)
    end

    it "between accounts, same entity" do
      Transfer.create(account: @account1, bank: @account1.bank, recipient: @account3.id, ammount: 2000)
      expect(Transfer.all.count).to eq(1)
      expect(Transfer.last.ammount).to eq(2000)
      expect(Transfer.last.account.funds).to eq(23000)
      expect(Account.find(Transfer.last.recipient).funds).to eq(7500)
    end

    it "between accounts, different entities, over limit" do
      Transfer.create(account: @account1, bank: @account1.bank, recipient: @account2.id, ammount: 1001)
      expect(Transfer.all.count).to eq(0)
    end

    it "between accounts, different entities, charge a fee" do
      Transfer.create(account: @account1, bank: @account1.bank, recipient: @account2.id, ammount: 999)
      expect(Transfer.all.count).to eq(1)
    end
  end
end
```

and the relevant model:

```
class Transfer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :bank

  before_save :bank_validator?

  validates :ammount, numericality: { less_than_or_equal_to: 1000 }, unless: :bank_validator?

  after_save :discount_from_origin
  after_save :add_to_recipient

  def discount_from_origin
    last_transfer = Transfer.last
    Account.discount_from_origin(last_transfer.account_id, last_transfer.ammount)
  end

  def add_to_recipient
    last_transfer = Transfer.last
    Account.add_to_recipient(last_transfer.recipient, last_transfer.ammount)
  end

  def bank_validator?
    bank_id == Bank.find(Account.find(recipient).bank_id)[:id]
  end
end
```

First two tests pass, the third one fails, even ammount is less than the 1000 limit for the validation.

Any help would be welcome. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the end, just needed to drop the before_save validation.